# Why can't I echo an acute accent in PHP?

Tags: php, echo, backticks

```
echo '´';
```

just shows a question mark. I also tried with double quotes, but the same thing happens.  I even tried adding a backslash in case it is an escaped character, but that just prints the backslash before the question mark.

I have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >` set, and going to Tools -> Page Info on Firefox shows UTF-8.

So why can't I echo an acute accent?

Comment: a) This is not a backtick, that's the ACUTE ACCENT. b) Works fine for me. What's the encoding of your source file?

Comment: Besides, the backtick is an ASCII character.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me.

I'm fairly sure that your *editor* is using an encoding different from UTF-8, <strike>most likely ISO-8859-1</strike> most likely UTF-16 (as @BoltClock points out, the backtick is a basic ASCII character so it would work if it were ISO-8859-1).

Comment: Thanks, but I also have some code that queries the database and echos a name from the database (which is UTF-8).  When a ´ is in the name, it displays correctly in PHPMyAdmin, but still just a question mark in the browser.  So it can't be the editor, because it also happens when ´ is taken directly from the database.

Comment: @CuppaJoe strange. Are you 10000% sure you are referring to the backtick character and not a fancy Unicode quote character?

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming so I'm fuzzy on this.  Is there some way I can verify that?  On my Swedish keyboard, it's to the left of the backspace (without pressing shift): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Keyboard_Layout_Swedish.png

Comment: @Cuppa nope, that is definitely the right one. This is really strange.  Any chance of a live link?

Comment: @Cuppa Without pressing shift it's a "foretick", or accute accent. With shift it'd either be the grave accent or a backtick (don't know).